# « Can I get a hell yeah! » : Comment exprimer cette phrase d'argot anglais ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, argot

Voici un [tweet de Women in Media](https://twitter.com/WomenNMedia/status/620730596310953984) :

> Can I get a hell yeah for our wo'men in media!

- Comment exprimer cette demande en français idiomatique ?
- Comment façonner une réponse qui garde l'esprit (de l'enthousiasme, de l'encouragement) de la question ? Le contexte est un mouvement qui favorise l'égalité pour les femmes : « Putain ! … » pourrait-il le meilleur choix pour « Hell yeah ! » ?

Answer (score 7):

Je ne suis pas certain que cette phrase entre bien dans la catégorie « argot ». C'est typiquement le genre de phrase que l'on pourrait entendre lors d'un concert, et qui sera régulièrement suivi par un : « Je ne vous entends pas ! » pour pousser à davantage de réaction.

#### Utilisation de « putain »

La partie la plus difficile à rendre correctement est le *Hell yeah!*. Je ne pense pas que « Putain ! » soit un bon choix ici : trop ambigu, il pourrait être pris pour l'inverse de ce qu'il est censé exprimer. Mal compris, on pourrait croire soit que tu es en rage de cette nouvelle, soit que tu insultes les personnes concernées.

« Putain, oui ! » peut éventuellement être utilisé pour marquer une réaction plus forte qu'un simple « oui » (« *Hell, yeah!* » n'est après tout qu'un « oui » avec beaucoup d'emphase). Cependant, *Hell* me semble être la version polie de *fuck* et à ce titre peut être toléré dans un registre courant, là où « putain » entre pour moi dans un registre familier.

#### Suggestion

« Hourra » est la forme la plus simple pour exprimer un enthousiasme collectif. On peut penser à quelque chose comme :

> Pour nos femmes dans les médias, hip hip hip...<sup>1</sup>

Pour quelque chose qui exprime explicitement l'attente de réaction :

> Pour nos femmes dans les médias, je veux entendre tout le monde crier « Hourra ! »<sup>2</sup>

Je pense que d'autres traductions sont possibles mais voici de quoi débuter.

---

<sub>1. Implique une réponse de groupe : « Hourra ! »</sub>

<sub>2. « Hourra ! » pourra être remplacé par une formule plus adéquate</sub>

Answer (score 2):

“Hell yeah” when said alone is, as mentioned by Chop in his good answer, just a way of saying “yes” with a lot of emphasis, but requesting/getting/giving a ‘Hell Yeah’ is also an edgy and familiar version of requesting/getting/giving [a/an “Amen”](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080415112347AAvQVIH) used to request/get/give enthusiastic approval of something (“Fuck Yeah,” as also correctly mentioned by Chop, takes the edginess, familiarity [, and emphasis] even further).
In English, getting/giving a/an “Amen [to that]” has expanded well beyond the walls of churches, where it originated, and it would be an appropriate replacement for "get[ting] a Hell Yeah" in this context (especially if "and for the good work they do" is added: "Can I have an "Amen" for the Women in Media and for the good work they do.")
In French, however, although “Amen” is also used outside church walls, I don’t think « Et maintenant, [peut-on avoir/disons] un grand ‘Amen’ à/pour …. » would work in your context to generate meaningful cries of “Amen”, although CNRTL does give this familiar sense: [“Exprime l'adhésion, le consentement. Dire *amen* à qqc.”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amen)

I do think, however, that

> Et maintenant, [nous pouvons/vous pouvez donner] [un grand ‘Bravo’ à/pour…
>   .](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/un%20grand%20bravo)

would work to elicit appropriate **applause and cries of “Bravo”** in response;

or if only **applause and/or other sounds of approval** were required, perhaps

> [Faites/faisons du bruit pour
>   …](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?q=faisons+du+bruit+pour&langFrom=fr&langTo=en&langTot=fr-en&translation)

would suffice in your context to capture “Let’s hear it for … .”